# How to convert AAR to JAR

Tags: java, jar, aar

***Situation***:

I intend to use a Java library and I only have an *AAR* file from a Maven repository but I need the *JAR* file.

*Background story:*

*I tried to compile a library, but its Gradle structure was unstable. So I asked for a compiled jar file, and its developer handed me an aar file from some Maven repository (the developer couldn't compile his own project).
The Gradle configuration was a mess, it depended on multiple libraries and Gradle has thrown some exceptions.*

*I tried to use it in my IDEA IDE, but it couldn't see it. A library project should be able to be compiled into a jar file, right?*

***Question***:

**What should I do to convert that AAR file to a JAR file?**

Comment: You can just rename it back to .jar but without knowing more details about your environment this may or may not be what you need to do, an AAR is an Axis library with specific uses.

Comment: You'll be laughing, but I had to add some non-regular word because SO wouldn't let my question be posted as it was so simple-worded. And I guess, it tells everything that the library's developer can't compile his own project using Gradle...

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The ***AAR*** file consists of a ***JAR*** file and some resource files (it is basically a standard zip file with a custom file extension). Here are the steps to convert:

1. Extract the AAR file using standard zip extract (rename it to **.zip* to make it easier)
2. Find the ***classes.jar*** file in the extracted files
3. Rename it as you like and use that jar file in your project

Comment: Interesting that this answer is accepted, because simply renaming a jar and copy it to your project's libs directory will not work due to the fact that the resource files are missing from the jar.

Comment: Following the tutorial for Spotify Android SDK, this answer was the remedy. This is because I develop projects in Netbeans, which seems to be not in compliance with the AAR extension. The remark of ChuongPham seems to be related not to this answer, but to the answer of AWT, and then I agree partly with ChuongPham, i.e. simple rename from AAR to JAR is not working. However, I also partly disagree because "resources" is not relevant for the classes.jar file.

Comment: I had a hard time finding out how to extract it on mac, in case others too: just change .aar to .zip and double click!

Comment: so what is the solution for creating a resource based jar ?

Comment: This solution only extract the jar file, but resources not contain in it. Something would be wrong.

Comment: @2cupsOfTech See my answer about resource based .aar-files

Comment: `jar xf example.aar` should extract the contents without issue.

Answer (score 22):

.aar is a standard zip archive, the same one used in .jar.  Just change the extension and, assuming it's not corrupt or anything, it should be fine.

If you needed to, you could extract it to your filesystem and then repackage it as a jar.

```
1) Rename it to .jar
2) Extract: jar xf filename.jar
3) Repackage: jar cf output.jar input-file(s)
```

Comment: When I run the jar xf, I get nothing: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>jar xf c:\dev\1\android-maps-utils-
0.2.1.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>

Comment: dude, step 1 is enough. Just rename it to .jar . In my view steps (2) and (3) are useless

Comment: @DrDeo If I just rename it, the eclipse project is not recognizing it as a library. Is it normal? Any clues?

Comment: If you just rename it and don't repackage it with jar, it's not going to have a manifest and it won't recognize it as a valid jar file, I believe.

Answer (score 16):

As many other people have pointed out, just extracting the .jar from the .aar file doesn't quite cut it as resources may be missing.

Here are the steps that worked for me (context of Android, your mileage may vary if you have other purposes):

1. Rename the .aar file to .zip and extract.
2. The extracted folder is an ADT project that you can import in Eclipse with some minor modifications (see below)!
3. In the extracted folder rename the contained file **classes.jar** to whatever you like (in this example myProjectLib.jar) and move it to the lib folder within the extracted folder.
4. Now in order for Eclipse to accept it you need to put two files into the extracted folder root:

   - .project
   - .classpath
5. To do that, create a new Android dummy project in Eclipse and copy over the files, or copy over from an existing Android project.
6. Open the .project file and look for the XML name tag and replace the contents of it with myProjectLib (or whatever you called your jar file above) and save.
7. Now in Eclipse you can **File -> New -> Project -> Android Project from existing source..** and point to the extracted folder content.
8. After import right click on the newly created project, select **Properties -> Android**, and check **Is Library**.
9. In your main project that you want to use the library for, also go to **Properties -> Android** and add the newly added myProjectLib to the list of dependencies.

Comment: This helped me. But in order to get if fully working, i needed to create an empty "src" folder between step 6 and 7.

Comment: I second that an empty src folder needs to be created. Also, once this procedure works (beautifully, because the steps are very clear), I had to delete its proguard.cfg references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74728030/2597758 + delete the old android-support-v4.jar from the app's libs folder.

Answer (score 8):

For those, who want to do it automatically, I have wrote a little two-lines bash script which does next two things:

1. Looks for all *.aar files and extracts classes.jar from them
2. Renames extracted classes.jar to be like the aar but with a new extension

   ```
   find . -name '*.aar' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d `dirname {}` {} classes.jar' \;
   find . -name '*.aar' -exec sh -c 'mv `dirname {}`/classes.jar `echo {} | sed s/aar/jar/g`' \;
   ```

That's it!

Comment: Sure, any aar2jar converting will not contain resources and manifest inside. We can say (not definitely but close to) that `aar=jar+res+manifest+libs`. Let `rest=res+manifest+libs`, than `jar(aar)=aar-rest`.

Comment: That's what I really want! Thank's a lot.  But it really increase the disk usage. because every support library has many version.  only unzip the latest verion may be better

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio (version: 1.3.2) allows you to seamlessly access the .jar inside a .aar.

Bonus: it automatically decompiles the classes!

Simply follow these steps:

1. `File > New > New Module > Import .JAR/.AAR Package` to import you .aar as a module
2. Add the newly created module as a dependency to your main project (not sure if needed)
3. Right click on "classes.jar" as shown in the capture below, and click "Show in explorer". Here is your .jar.

[image: access .jar from .aar]

Comment: first must select project instead of android in project manager then external libraries will show

Answer (score 6):

**Resource based .aar-projects**

Finding the classes.jar file inside the .aar file is pretty trivial. However, that approach does not work, if the .aar-project defined some resources (example: R.layout.xyz)

- Therefore [deaar](https://gist.github.com/commonsguy/a3a534ea28ef8a82a213) from CommonsGuy helped me to get a valid
  ADT-friendly project out of an .aar-file. *In my case I converted
  [subsampling-scale-image-view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view). It took me about an hour to set up ruby on my PC.*
- Another approach is using android-maven-plugin for Eclipse/ADT [as
  CommonsGuy writes in his blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html).
- Yet another approach could be, just cloning the whole desired project
  as source from git and import it as "Existing Android project"

Comment: Is approach #3 the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/37747277/2597758 ?

Answer (score 5):

```
 The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project. .aar file 
 consists a JAR file and some resource files. You can convert it
 as .jar file using this steps

1) Copy the .aar file in a separate folder and Rename the .aar file to .zip file using 
 any winrar or zip Extractor software.

2) Now you will get a .zip file. Right click on the .zip file and select "Extract files". 
 Will get a folder which contains "classes.jar, resource, manifest, R.java,
 proguard(optional), libs(optional), assets(optional)".

3) Rename the classes.jar file as yourjarfilename.jar and use this in your project.
```

> Note: If you want to get only .jar file from your .aar file use the
>   above way.
>       Suppose If you want to include the manifest.xml and resources with your .jar file means
>       you can just right click on your .aar file and save it as .jar file directly instead of
>       saving it as a .zip. To view the .jar file which you have extracted, download [JD-GUI(Java Decompiler)](http://jd.benow.ca/). Then drag and drop your .jar file into this JD_GUI, you can see the .class file in readable formats like a .java file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this mean that we can use the AAR file like a JAR file just by renaming it from .aar to .jar?

Comment: @Soumya, no, you cannot.

Comment: Actually the topic of the conversation is wrong. We cannot convert AAR to JAR or vice-versa. The only thing we can do is "extract JAR from AAR". And I have wrote how to do this automaticaly using two lines of Bash code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29252592/746529

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gradle for your builds - there is a Gradle plugin which allows you to add aar dependency to your java|kotlin|scala|... modules.

https://github.com/stepango/aar2jar

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.stepango.aar2jar' version “0.6” // <- this one
}

dependencies {
    compileOnlyAar "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0" // <- Use any AAR dependencies
}
```

Comment: Trying to understand, is it possible to make 'compileOnlyAar' for android app/lib plugin? i know that it's not about your library, but maybe you know is it possible since, android plugin doesn't contain artifact configuration like 'compileOnlyAar'. You can understand why i need this functionality here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998072/how-to-make-an-equivalent-of-compileonly-for-aar-artifacts)

Comment: your quotes are broken, and I can't edit because the edit queue is full