# Can't find Android Support Repository in SDK Manager

Tags: sdk, android-sdk-manager

I am following this: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
At step 2, I can't seem to find an option to download Android Support Repository in the Extras folder.

[image]

In the extras folder, you can see there's no option to download it. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I can't see that ether in my packages list.. I think it's just meaning the "Android Support Library" that you all ready have installed.. I never had needed anything else..

Comment: @Hardy Yeah, I never had the need for anything extra, but I am experimenting with google ads so I need these extra things.

Comment: I have also used google ads and never needed anything else.. Do you have then some compile issues or something? Missing classes?

Comment: @Hardy Oh no, I'm just following the steps from the android website, I'm not even sure if I need those or not, just following them

Comment: Ok :) i am sure you can continue without bothering about that anymore :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Under **Tools**, select **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-tools** and update.

[image]

Once updated, restart your SDK Manager. **Android Support Repository** will now be available under **Extras**.

[image]

Comment: hmm. doesn't work for me (android sdk tools now at 24.4.1). There's something called "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries" which I'm going to try installing. Perhaps it's just been renamed?

Comment: doesn't works for me too. android sdk tools is 24.4.1 and platform tools is 23.1 and build tools is 23.0.2. Is these all at last version? I have not access to main google repository but I have used mirror for it (mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn).

Comment: Same here. Am on android sdk tools 24.4.1, platform tools 23.1 and build tools 23.0.2, still not seeing Support Repository

Comment: It was renamed. Install "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries" now.

Comment: I have not installed android sdk platform-tools still I could able to download Local Maven repository for Support Libraries. Actually the problem was that it got renamed to Local Maven repository for Support Libraries. Thanks to @Jeiwan

Comment: It appears as though the name has been changed back?  I updated `Local Maven repository for Support Libraries` from rev 27 to rev 30 and it is now (once again) called `Android Support Repository`.  This is weird.

Answer (score 12):

As of today, the android support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

by adding maven section in repositories tag in build.gradle of project.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

kehers answer worked before but now that library has been renamed to:

**Local Maven repository for Support Libraries** and its also under Extras.

Comment: I am using android studio 4.0 and I can't find this Library.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same problem. You should update your Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools. That will bring the option of Support Repository.

Comment: I do have Android Support Repository but nowhere to see Android Support Library???!!!???

Answer (score 3):

From the Android developers website: "The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the SDK Manager, and that functionality will be removed soon..."

The support libraries can be found here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support

Once you find the library you want, download the .aar file then use the steps provided by rsp1984 in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar) post to convert the .aar file into the library.

Answer (score 2):

1) On the menu bar, select **Packages** and check obsolete packages

2) Now check for the support library

Answer (score 0):

Now, it looks like the supporter library have been simply removed.

Tools installed

[image: Tools]

Extra library

[image: Extra library]

In consequence, Bazel / Android support is now broken.

Comment: Same problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The main error is in the Build File. The maven URL must be HTTPS but not HTTP:

[image]