# Android support libraries in maven repository that's available online

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a build server that is used to generate APKs. Now, some of those APKs require Google support libraries as dependencies, like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

Now the way I've solved problem is to [update "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703769/237858). But I find it silly to do this every time new support libraries are released.

So, is there online maven repository that I can add to gradle buildscript as repository to resolve these Google support packages? Like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        // someMagicalMavenRepoThatContainsSupportLibraries()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use this link :

```
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4/r6
```

Comment: That was posted in 2012... Isn't the latest revision 23 or 24 now?