# Install google repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following an online tutorial where it is asked to install Google repository by:

1. Going to SDK manager > SDK tools > expand Support Repository (after Google Services is installed) > install Google Repository

I installed Google Services in my SDK tools, but I cannot even see the Support Repository in my SDK tools. What could be the problem?

Comment: As of now **Support Repository** are  no longer downloadable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find Android Support Repository in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598552/cant-find-android-support-repository-in-sdk-manager)