# How to use DonutProgress library in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using android studio for developing my project .In my project i have donutProgress library in form of aar format. It is working fine. Now i want to migrate the project to eclipse. I migrated and removed the error in the project. There is no error in my project but, when it is going to the page which uses the donutProgress lib, it is giving a crash with following error.

```
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.meawallet.main-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.meawallet.main-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
05-20 20:00:48.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17766):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
```

Comment: Why would you migrate to eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode the jar file and take the java file and directly use its class with the required resource for the above implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the library, in .jar format, and include it in your Eclipse project. You can found it [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.github.lzyzsd%3Acircleprogress/1.1.0/view#files)

Comment: Isn't it possible to use *.aar files within eclipse as well?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, you can't. However [someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar/21485222#21485222) said that you can. This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not include the library correclty.

This could happen if you added the library for compile time but not for runtime. Don't know, how that can happen anymore, since I believe, you should not use Eclipse (only if you really need it i.e. NDK)

Comment: But if the library is not correctly included then the code will give error while building . Instead it builds correctly ,but it crashes .So is there any solution for fixing it.