# Where can I find .jar files of android's .aar dependencies

Tags: android, maven, jar, dependencies

Where can this (`com.android.support:support-v4:jar:21.0.3`) dependency be found in for download.  Android's SDK manager provides a support library, but it is in the .aar format.  No longer can I find a .jar of the support library.

```
com.android.support:support-v4:jar:21.0.3
```

Comment: Any reason why you need .jars?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can this (com.android.support:support-v4:jar:21.0.3) dependency be found in for download.

On your hard drive, if you have the "Android Support Library" installed from the SDK Manager. It will be in `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/v4/`, where it has been for the past few years.

> Android's SDK manager provides a support library, but it is in the .aar format.

Only as part of the "Android Support Repository", which is primarily for use by Android Studio and other Gradle for Android users.

Comment: It looks like after 19.1.0 jars are no longer being provided, but only aars.

Comment: @TheTokenizer: I don't know how you are determining that. The Android SDK Manager shows it as 22.2, and the date on my file is May 28 of this year.

Comment: @TheTokenizer the jar on my machine this was located in $ANDROID_SDK/extra/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/

That folder contains, the jars, aars, javadoc, pom, sha, and md5s.

Comment: @EGHDK: That's the Android Support Repository, and, like The Tokenizer is seeing, I only see AARs there, in terms of binaries. There are JAR files, but those contain source code and docs, and so really are just ZIP files.

Comment: @CommonsWare are the .jar sources not the jars you're looking for Tokenizer?

Comment: @TheTokenizer you can also try just changing the aar on your filesystem to a zip, then unzip and you will find the .jar there. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485222/1193321