# Call requires API level 23 (current min is 14): android.app.Activity#requestPermissions,checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying add run time permissions android(6.0.1) API 23,If I use SDK version(**min and target version both 23**) it woks fine, like below,

```
    <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="23"
                android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

If I change android:minSdkVersion(less then 23)

For example:

I am getting error below:

> Call requires API level 23 (current min is 14):
>   android.app.Activity#requestPermissions,checkSelfPermission

For following 2 methods,

```
1)requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS)

2)checkSelfPermission(permission)
```

I tried `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` and `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` both are not working.

What I missing could not understand..

Comment: ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() is exactly what you want, could you please be more specific about why it's not working?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when using ActivityCompat or ContextCompat? If yes, what error?

Comment: following is the error I am getting if  I use  ActivityCompat  "The method checkSelfPermission(String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat"

Comment: It's not ActivityCompat, it's ContextCompat.

Comment: @Egor this code I am using ContextCompat.requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);                                                                                                                                                Following is the error I am getting, "The method requestPermissions(String[], int) is undefined for the type ContextCompat"

Comment: @Joe Please check my answer below

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Either check for target >=23 or simply add below line above your method

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

For example, If you are checking for storage permissions, then you can refer to this function,

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public boolean CheckStoragePermission() {
        int permissionCheckRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheckRead != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        Define.PERMISSION_STORAGE);
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        Define.PERMISSION_STORAGE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your solution also works :)

Comment: Where can I add code to handle the case as the user denied the permission, like exit the application?

Answer (score 40):

**Check for permissions:**

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context context, String permission)`

**Request permissions:**

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode)`

or inside a support-v4 `Fragment`

`requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode)`

Answer (score 20):

try this way

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestContactsPermissions1();
    } else {
        // your code
    }
}
```

---

EDITED:

Add in dependencies block in lower-level(your app) `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

or add below only if you need design support lib

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

use one of above

Comment: following is the error I am getting if  I use  ActivityCompat  "The method checkSelfPermission(String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat"

Comment: @Joe: check edited answer

Comment: I think it is better to use simpler alternative - just annotate class or method with the @TargetApi(23) because on API version less than 23 permissions are granted automatically so condition block has no sense. So anyone who suggests condition alternative have useless code indent and possibly useless "else" block.

Answer (score 7):

That is because `checkSelfPermission()` was added in **API 23**. So you'll have to code conditionally like:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //use checkSelfPermission()
} else {
    //simply use the required feature
    //as the user has already granted permission to them during installation
}
```

Comment: following is the error I am getting if  I use  ActivityCompat  "The method checkSelfPermission(String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat"

Comment: @Joe Did you have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34613112/5352802

Comment: Ya looks like I have the same problem,I am using eclipse,how to add could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Joe Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17903778/5352802

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem :)

Comment: @Joe glad to hear it! Mark as accepted? :)

Answer (score 1):

check the device sdk before calling the request permission

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
//call the request permission here 
}
```