# How to integrate paypal in android 4.3?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal SDK 2.10.0 on Android 4.3.

I have the error in ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX

request failed with server response:null

SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR

with Dialog box "There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers. Please try again."

Is their any guide for PayPal integration in android ? I am new to android, but i have done work with PayPal on websites before.

it's working on Android 5.0 and above .

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "*****************************************************************";

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)         
        .merchantName("TapTop");


Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
    startService(intent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was a probelm with paypal 2.10.0, try with new version

```
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
```

It is resolved in new update, you can check related issue [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/228)

**Advice :**

Please take one look at perticular sdk/library in github, check issues of that library, if you find related issue there, no need to ask question here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already checked that and you can see the last comment is very similar to mine. The problem with 2.13.1 is that its not a jar file, but its a aar file.  I am using eclipse which doesnt support aar files. As i said i am a bit new to android. Can you suggest anything for that. Is it possible to convert aar to jar ?

Comment: yes thn in second last comment its already given [How to convert AAR to JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar)

Comment: That doesnt work. I tried, but when i try to use. Its broken.