# OsmDroid - OSMBonusPack - GenericMapView cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapsforge

I updated from:
'*osmdroid-android-4.3 + osmbonuspack_v5.1*' to '*osmdroid-android-5.1 + osmbonuspack_v5.7*'

Aswell I imported the '*osmdroid-third-party-5.1.jar*'

Then I checked the source code of the OsmNavigator and found that the mapView is created different than the older version of OsmDroid:

```
//map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    GenericMapView genericMap = (GenericMapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    MapTileProviderBasic bitmapProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
    genericMap.setTileProvider(bitmapProvider);
    map = genericMap.getMapView();
```

**Error: GenericMapView cannot be resolved to a type**

I can't do: `import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.mapsforge.GenericMapView;`

**Question: Where do I find the package:`org.osmdroid.bonuspack.mapsforge.GenericMapView;`?**

Comment: where can you get osmdroid-third-party-5.1.jar? (not aar) can you upload it somethere please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In osmbonuspack/MapsForgeForOsmdroid

If you are including OSMBonusPack with Gradle and Jitpack, add this:

```
dependencies {
        ...
        compile 'com.github.MKergall.osmbonuspack:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:v5.7'
}
```

Comment: Is there a .jar file I can use?

Comment: https://jitpack.io/com/github/MKergall/osmbonuspack/MapsForgeForOsmdroid/v5.7/MapsForgeForOsmdroid-v5.7.aar

Comment: MKer this is aar, not jar

Comment: The .aar file contains the .jar file! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485222/4885562