# How to add Google Play Service 9.0.2 Library to Eclipse Android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, google-play-services

I search hardly for a way to add Google Play Service Libraries to my Android Project in Eclipse. I need a version > 9.0.0 and found no way yet.

The documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) still says the library's jar file can be found under `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`.
But since some versions ago it's been reorganized and to find splitted up under `<android-sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/`.

I tried to unpack the .aar files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar) but it won't work. I'm working with Eclipse 4.5.1 on Ubuntu Linux 64bit.

Any ideas how to get it to work?
Many thanks!

Comment: There's a reason there's no documentation: Eclipse has been deprecated for over a year now.

Comment: I didn't notice, but makes sense. Thanks a lot!