# Android studio create .jar file instead of .aar file

Tags: android, jar, aar

Hi I followed android documentation to create a library. But my problem is whenever I run the project means it is creating .aar file. I google it and found [How to convert AAR to JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar)
this. I'm using iZip Unarchiver. But it is not extracting the .aar file. 
But they accepted that answer. Can any one know how to extract .jar from .aar. Thank you.

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want to do that? You're missing all additional stuff, like assets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly generate jar file using android studio. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i4I-Nph-Cw) is a good tutorial for this.

Comment: Thank you. I gives me the idea. No need to extract jar. We have it in build->intermediates->bundles->release->classes.jar. We can rename and use it.