# eclipse + eclim + android support library

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, eclim

I have an android gradle project which I compile from the command line. I am using eclipse + eclim to have autocompletion and source code validation. I was an unable to get code completion to work by importing the project as an gradle project into eclipse. I therefore imported `/path/to/gradle/project/app/src/main` as an android project into eclipse and after some `.classpath` tweaking I was able to get autocompletion to work.

Now I wanted to import the following android support libraries:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

but got `The import ... cannot be resolved` error for all three lines. I then tried **Android Tools -> Add Android Support Library** which failed miserably. I then tracked down the libraries in question in the **Android-SDK** and added them manually to the Java Build Path in Eclipse. For some I needed to extract the JAR files from the AAR files as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar/21485222#21485222). I added the following libraries:

```
appcompat-v7-26.0.0-alpha1.jar
support-annotations-26.0.0-alpha1.jar
support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.jar
support-v13-26.0.0-alpha1.jar
```

This solved the problem for the the first two imports but I still get the error for `import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;`. I have code completion up to `v4` but `app` is not found.

How can I resolve this issue? Am I still missing some dependency? Is there a better way to get android code completion with eclim?

Comment: I would suggest using Android Studio. Google stopped supporting Eclipse for the development of Android apps almost two years ago. Android studio has autocompletion and source code validation build in.

Comment: @Rockney Well then I don't have autocompletion in vim via eclim anymore. But I essentially want to know if it is still possible to use eclim with android or if everything has to go via Android Studio these days.

Comment: I don't know a lot about vim, but it will get harder to use Eclipse for Android development, because they stopped supporting it. I would suggest checking if it is possible to integrate Android studio with vim. You might find these links usefull https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-intellij-idea-as-the-vim-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out myself. There was still a dependency missing. In my case I also needed

```
 support-compat-26.0.0-alpha1.jar
```

I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/FiV0/ac63421b9c03cae277bd356393a70d29) script to extract all the jar class files that are somewhere hidden in the `android-sdk/folder`. It recursivly looks at all subdirectories of the specified Android SDK folder until it either finds a JAR file which is not Javadoc or Source and copies it to a destination directory. If an AAR file is found the content is extracted to a folder of the same name as described in the link of the question and the JAR file in that folder copied with an appropriate name to the given destination directory.