# Example project doesn't work

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I use a mac with OS X El Capitan with Eclipse IDE

When I create a project "Gluon Mobile - Single View Project" I can not compile for Android because I have a problem with multidex. I use this command :

```
./gradlew androidInstall
 Execution failed for task ':mergeClassesIntoJar'.
 > Cannot expand ZIP '/.../sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar' 
 as it does not exist.
```

I saw differents topics and I did these verifications :

- Android SDK is installed by "Android Studio"
  [But, I don't have android support library to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeUgM.png)
- If I add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' on my build.gradle, I have an another error

  ```
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
  > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0.
  ```
- But if I add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' in a random Android Studio project, gradle compile.
- Compilation for Desktop is OK, on iPhone Simulation too.

I don't understand why It's doesn't working

Thank you for your reading. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the list of [prerequisites](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/latest/#_android) for deploying on Android, you need:

- the Android SDK
- the Build-tools
- And the Android Support Library

Open Android SDK manager (from /tools, run `./android`), and make sure you install the Android Support Library from `Extras`:

[image: Extras]

Comment: Hello, yes I do all the prerequisites.
I just downloaded again the sdk manager and launch (from /tools, run ./android).
Android Support Library is not present ! Just Android Support Repository is here.

Comment: Which Android platforms have you installed?

Comment: The SDK platform  21 and the Build-tools 21.1.2 too

Comment: Try installing platform 23 as well as the build tools for this platform.

Comment: I just do it and nothing changed

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html), maybe it is because you already have the Android Support Repository installed. Can you uninstall it and try again?

Comment: I uninstall it and unluckily Android Support Library doesn't appear. I don't understand why I don't have the option to install the Library.

Comment: Can you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23436671/3956070)? It seems it allows manually installing it

Comment: Can you double check you have the 'Obsolete' checkbox ticked as in answer above.  On my install the support library shows as 'Android Support Library (Obsolete)'

Comment: Yes It's working after install Obsolete Android Support Library.

Answer (score 1):

android sdk has change its folders and gluon older version is targeted for the older android sdk folders . so  , change the gluon script for its newest version in gradle  . 
change build.gradle  classpath (/your_project/Build Scripts/Projects/build.gradle)

> classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:x.x.x'

for this

> classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.3'

Answer (score 0):

A commenter on an answer above answered this, but it's buried in comments so I'm putting it as an answer so those who don't read every comment don't miss it:

"Can you double check you have the 'Obsolete' checkbox ticked as in answer above. On my install the support library shows as 'Android Support Library (Obsolete)'"
     -user2145222

The previous answer shows a screenshot where this checkbox is checked, but unless you EXTREMELY observant, you wouldn't really notice it.

This single solution did it for me!

Comment: I have the same problem although 'Android Support Library (Obsolete)' is installed on my system.  The problem is the search path.  android-support-multidex.jar seems to be no longer located in extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/ but in extras/android/compatibility/multidex/library/libs.