# Visual Studio can't install Android SDK (API level 19 and 21) (missing extra-android-support)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

After trying to install Android SDK (API level 19 and 21) for Visual Studio via it's updater, I always see the error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMC3.png)

I reinstalled Visual Studio, JDK and even Windows, but nothing changed.
Than I checked if this "extra-android-support" package exist, and I found that there'are no more that package in Android repository.

You can check it by yourself, if you go to Android SDK folder\tools

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

And then run next command in cmd

```
android.bat update sdk -u -a –-filter extra-android-support
```

Looks like there's no package with this name anymore: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R4jr.png).

But Visual Studio is still trying to install it. Is there anyways how can I use Android SDK for Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382555/android-support-library-manual-download)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Visual Studio is still trying to install it. Is there anyways how can I use Android SDK for Visual Studio?

You can ignore this error and go ahead use the android SDK for Visual Studio without problem.

If you want to install the latest android SDK Platform or other android tools, you can open the android sdk manager through VS: ***Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager***

Or you can open the android sdk manager directly under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`(please open it with Administrator).